# Why JBoss7.1.0EAP giving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace Error when deploying 2 ear files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-8, jboss

I have 2 ear file say 1.ear and 2.ear
when I deploy each of them individually to the my local Jboss 7.1.0.eap deployment folder. They run just fine.
But When I try to deploy both of them together , it deploys fine , but when try to call one of the ear , the server starts giving  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace Error in the log. Any idea how to resolve this, or what is the best way to deploy and run both of them together.

Error Log:

```
15:47:24,753 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-1) Failed to define class org.aspectj.weaver.World$TypeMap in Module "deployment.icam-e.ear.icam-e-web-1.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.OutOf
oryError: Metaspace
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:713)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.World.<init>(World.java:58)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld.<init>(ReflectionWorld.java:53)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.setClassLoader(PointcutParser.java:228)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.<init>(PointcutParser.java:214)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.getPointcutParserSupportingSpecifiedPrimitivesAndUsingSpecifiedClassLoaderForResolution(PointcutParser.java:169)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.initializePointcutParser(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:241)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:220)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:176)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:224)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:283)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:315)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:74)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:352)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)

15:47:24,829 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (default task-1) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.b
s.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
15:47:24,831 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
cContentNegotiationManager': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
```

Comment: Increase the size of your meta space in JDK 8: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55119_01/doc.71/e55122/cnf_jvmgc.htm#WSEAD414

Comment: Thanx duffymo...increasing the metaspace parameter in JBoss JAVA_OPTS option resolved the issue

Comment: Glad to help.  Be sure to take a look at your WAR/EAR files to make sure that they are as lean as they can be.  JARs are loaded into meta space.  You can exhaust it by loading unnecessary JARs.

Comment: Sure..I will check..thnx